# Rails, render a different header just on homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a rails app and I must differentiate the header for home page.

I already created a partial with the _home_header version and the _header version to use in every page, but I don't know how can I manage the change.

The header is included in my layout, and I render the same layout for every page. How can I tell to "layout" to use the _home_header version instead of the standard version when I request homepage?

Comment: Can you use content_for in the view for the homepage? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would use the `current_page?` helper and look at the `root_path`.

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<% if current_page?(root_path) %>
    <%= render 'layouts/home_header' %>
<% else %>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this in `application.html.erb`

```
<% if request.original_url == root_url %>  ## Specify the home url instead of root_url(if they are different)
  <%= render 'layouts/home_header' %>      ## Assuming that _home_header.html.erb is under layouts directory
<% else %>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>           ## Assuming that _header.html.erb is under layouts directory
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you add more specific versions of pages in controller-specific sub directories.

That is, if you have a layout `application.html.erb` which renders a header partial...

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<!doctype html>
<html>
...
<body>
  <%= render 'header' %>
  ...
```

This will look for a `header` partial first in `app/views/<controller_name>/` then in `app/views/application/`. So, your site-wide header would reside in `app/views/application/_header.html.erb`, and your homepage partial would reside in `app/views/home/_header.html.erb`, and it would "just work". Rails would load the more "specific" header.

Comment: I know but I must add the default version in every view... i need just to override the header when I load homepage.

Answer (score 1):

An option to @meagar suggestion would be use a `before_action` on your application controller for that:

```
class ApplicationController
  beore_action :set_header

  private

    def set_header
      @header = if is_my_page
        "Special header"
      else
        "Other header"
      end
    end
end
```

and in your `layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<title><%=@title%></title>
```

The bright part of his solution is that all text are kept on the view files, which makes sense. The not-so-bright part is that is harder to follow.